# How to make div visible even if we are hiding the page visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

In one single page, I have two different pages with id `leftPanel` and `rightPanel` respectively. On clicking expand button, I want that right panel display should be none except a `div` present on it. How can I achieve this? There is a div called `mydiv` on `rightPanel`. `myDiv` should be visible on expand.

```
function expand() {
    document.getElementById("rightpanel").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: You should include some basic html that uses the function for better readability.

Comment: Could not understand

Comment: if myDiv is inside rightPanel you can't make rightPanel display:none and expect myDiv to show, you would have to move the myDiv outside